# Having issues maping <C-j> and <C-h> in vim

Tags: key-bindings, split

I tried to remap my split navigation like [explained here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/vim-splits-move-faster-and-more-naturally#easier-split-navigations). Moving to the top  or right split  works but ther other two just do nothing. I tried the same without a .vimrc which led to the same result. Later i tried the same in GVim where all of them worked so i guessed it has something to do with vim running in the terminal. Then i figured out that pressing  in my terminal doesn't act like backspace as it should.
What can i do to fix this?

Comment: You're on Windows, I assume? Terminal vim on windows gets mapped to `<C-h>`, however this still shouldn't mess up your mapping so I'm not sure what's going on there. To fix the backspace issue you can do `inoremap <C-h> <BS>`, but I can't say that I know why `<C-j>` and `<C-h>` aren't working.

Comment: No i'm on Linux Mint. Just installed terminator and there it works. Seems to be some issue with Gnome Terminal.

Answer (score 4):

Your comment indicates that this problem exists only with certain terminal emulators like gnome-terminal

> No I'm on Linux Mint. Just installed terminator and there it works. Seems to be some issue with Gnome Terminal

Gnome-terminal is known to have trouble with mapping modifier keys in vim

Example: The problem is that in a terminal, a Tab character is ^I (Control-I). This means that pressing control while pressing tab is not something the terminal even bothers to pass through to Vim. It just sends a regular tab character.

GVim can support this because it doesn't have to rely on the terminal to tell it what keys are being pressed in what combination--it has more direct access to keyboard events, so it has no trouble seeing modified special keys.

While it's possible for X to recognize such combinations, applications that run in a terminal (or, these days, a terminal emulator) cannot. This is because, historically, terminals could only send and receive seven- or eight-bit sequences of ASCII data across a serial connection (though this could include "escape sequences" that position the cursor, scroll or delete lines, change color and other helpful effects).

There are some workarounds for it:

First, we need to know what command your terminal sends when a certain key combination is pressed:

To do so press `Control + Shift + v`
Now press the key combination `Ctrl-j` and `Ctrl-h`

Ex: I am running headless server and for me `Shift+Enter` or `Control+Enter` or `Enter` shows the same output `^M` but `Alt+Enter` shows `^[` This means that shift+enter and control+enter and enter are taken similarly by the terminal.
So mapping `shift+enter` combination would also affect `enter` combinations.

2. Record your output

enter gives me `^M` and `\r`

3. man ascii

Look in the manpages of ascii and you will see that `\r` is for `CR` 
so now mapping `<CR>` will map enter keys

Following these methods you might be able to find the specific `char`

Even though it should solve the problem, YMMV

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated  [various proposals](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8)..

> Vim's keyboard input system revolves centrally around a queue of bytes.
>   This worked well when all the world was serial terminals. In this new
>   world of GUIs this model doesn't work so well. I advocate changing it to
>   a queue of keypress events.

Comment: Thank you for all that information. I did what you suggested and noticed that there is no output for `Ctrl - g` `Ctrl - h` and `Ctrl - j` while `Ctrl - f` opened a search window. So i looked at Gnome Terminals Shortcuts and found that these four combinations were mapped to find actions. Unmapping them solved my problem!

Comment: Ah ! Glad your problem is solved. I had a doubt that those keys were already mapped. Happy to help !