# Cannot map <C-j> sequence in vim

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

I used to be able to navigate vim splits using

```
nnoremap <C-j> <C-w>j
nnoremap <C-k> <C-w>k
nnoremap <C-l> <C-w>l
nnoremap <C-h> <C-w>h
```

but now I cannot map the `<C-j>` sequence to any other command. Is this key combination not allowed to be remapped anymore?

I tried an empty .vimrc file (apart from the 4 lines above) and it does not work when using `:sp` for a horizontal split. All other navigation mappings work as expected. If I use other keys instead of `j` it also works. I tried on both gnome-terminal and the termite terminal emulators, running on Arch Linux.
Im using vim 8.1:

```
:version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1
```

Edit: If I log into vim and type `:nnoremap` I see a list of the mappings for `h`, `k` and `l`, but *not* for `j`. If I then type `:nnoremap <C-j> <C-w>j` everything works fine. For some reason, vim is not loading the `<C-j>` map from the `.vimrc` file...

Comment: @HerbWolfe the answer in the link you provided says its not a good idea to map <C-j> in insert mode only, but I'm trying on normal mode. Also, the command `let g:BASH_Ctrl_j = 'off'` did not have any effect.

I have updated my question with new information.

Comment: The upvoted answer also says that Ctrl-J is interpreted as a null byte. See also these answers to similar questions: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3570/5298 and https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/10716/5298, in particular the comments regarding Gnome-Terminal.

Comment: I don't think my problem is the same as in the other questions. As I stated in the OP, running the command `:nnoremap <C-j> <C-w>j` inside vim fixes the problem. This happens in gvim and vim, using gnome-terminal, termite, or xterm.

Comment: I have fixed the issue, `vim-latexsuite` was interfering with the mappings. Removing the `vim-latexsuite` package solved the problem.